# change backcolor of part of text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, backcolor

i have some part of text with html tags , for example

```
<b>something</b>
```

i select some part of text for example "some".

with getSelection().getRangeAt(0);  i get position of caret (textcursor), so i know which part of text i've selected.

i have startOffset and endOffset. but problem is, that startOffset and endOffset ignores html tags, so numbers which it returns are not bad, and then i don't know on which part of text i have to apply

```
<span style="background-color: somecolor ">some</span>
```

any ides how to solve this ? thanks

Comment: just found this, and going to read that, maybe will help http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<b id='str1'>something</b>
<script>
function jsReplace()
{
  var elem = document.getElementById('str1')
  elem .innerHTML = elem .innerHTML.replace('some', '<span style="background-color: somecolor ">some</span>')

}
</script>
```

Comment: yes, but what will you do , if there isn't id in that b tag ?

Comment: how do you get your string and from which control?

Comment: with selection and range,   user selects text with mouse

Comment: ok use getSelection()
function jsReplace()
{
  var str= document.getSelection() /*supposing it's ie, u could try window.getSelection and document.selection*/
  str=str.replace('some', '<span style="background-color: somecolor ">some</span>')

}

and apply the function onmousedown